# Populate Django Model with for-loop

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model `Task` which I want to populate with a for loop.
In a list I have the tasks that should be passed into the model.

My model has actually more than three tasks (Below I have shown only three). The list will also have varying number of entries. The list can also have only one task.

```
tasks = ['first task', 'second task', 'third task']



class Task(models.Model):
    ad = models.OneToOneField(Ad, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
    task1 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    task2 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    task3 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Tasks for {self.ad}'
```

My approach looks like this:

```
task_obj = Task.objects.create(
    ad = ad
)
for idx, t in enumerate(tasks):
    task_obj.f'task{idx+1}' = t
```

Basically this part `f'task{idx+1}'` should not be a string, but the actual variable of the model.

Is this even possible? Or does an other way exist I am not aware of?

Comment: Are you trying to do child tasks? On the contrary, I would add the parent field, and inside the task I would collect a list of subtasks for which the current one is the parent

Comment: But if you want to do exactly child tasks, I would create a SubTask class that has text and a parent element of the Task class to which the Foreign key would refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) built-in function to set dynamic attributes:

```
for idx, t in enumerate(tasks):
    setattr(task_obj, f'task{idx+1}', t)
```